# Cluster sampling with R or SAS

Tags: r, sas, survey

I do have 155k points distributed in 2k groups. There are 3 kind of points (A+B+C=#points)

Frequency distribution:

```
  Gr #clients    #A    #B    #C
-------------------------------
  01      100    80    10    10
  02       10     0     3     7

2000      400   300    80    20
--------------------------------
TOTAL: 155000 93000 46500 15500
```

I want to select random **groups of points** to a total of 6,000 points, such as the proportions of each type of point in the sample is the same than in the population.

Is there a method for this in R or SAS? or should I perform a simple random survey and then design some algorithm of group substitution till I get the balanced sample?,

Comment: could you provide some fake data?  :)  [this page has a clear explanation of how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not statistician so I can't be sure from my answer. That's said I think you are confusing balanced and cluster sampling. Typing this , `library(sos),findFn('cluster sampling')`, may help you. See for example , sampling package and function cluster or samplecube

Comment: Do you want to sample from the groups in such a way that the total fraction of A in the sample equals that of the population 93000/155000 (the same for B and C)? Do the groups all need to have the same inclusion probability?

Comment: Do you need to sample many times or only once?

Answer (score 1):

### EXAMPLE 1: THIS IS HOW I WOULD DO IT IN SAS. If code makes you nervous, use the simpler method in EXAMPLE 2, below.

> Note: What you're describing sounds like a proportional sample, not a
>   cluster sample, so that's what I've shown here. Hope that meets your
>   needs.

```
      /******** sort by strata *****/
      proc sort data=MED_pts_155k ; by GRoup A_B_C clients ; run ;

      /******** create sample design ***/
      proc surveyselect noprint  
      data= MED_pts_155k   
      method=srs  
      seed = 7  
      n = 6000  
      out = sample_design ;  
      strata GRoup A_B_C  /  
        alloc=prop NOSAMPLE
        allocmin = 2  ; /*** min of 2 per stratum.  ****/  
     run ;

    /******** pull sample **********/
    proc surveyselect noprint
      data= MED_pts_155k
      method=sys
      seed = &seed 
      n = sample_design
      out = MY_SAMPLE ;
     strata GRoup A_B_C  ; 
    run ;
```

> The "alloc = prop" option gives you proportional (i.e. 'even') sampling.  The "nosample" option in SAS allows you to generate a separate file outlining the sample design.  You then use the design in a second stage where you actually pull the sample.  If this is too much bother you can leave off the "nosample" option, and go straight to pulling your sample as we
>    as we did in the simpler example below.
>
> Note that in the second step above we've chosen to switch to 'method = SYS', instead of simple random sample (SRS).  SRS would work too, but since you may have different types of responses by client, you might want to sample in a representative way across the range of clients.  To do that you sort within each stratum by client and intentionally sample in even increments across the range of clients; this is a called a  "systematic" sample (SYS).

### EXAMPLE 2: SIMPLER

**You could also do it all in one simple step if you want less code, and don't need to see the sample design broken down in a separate file.**

```
/******** sort by strata *****/
proc sort data=MED_pts_155k ; by GRoup A_B_C ; run ;

/******** pull sample **********/
proc surveyselect noprint
  data= MED_pts_155k
  method= SRS
  seed = 7 
  n = 6000
  out = MY_SAMPLE ;
 strata GRoup A_B_C  / 
    alloc=prop 
    allocmin = 2  ; 
run ;
```

> In both examples we're assuming you have two stratification variables:
>   'GRoup' and a second variable 'A_B_C' which contains values of a, b.
>   or c.  Hope that helps.   Cluster sampling is possible in SAS as well, but as noted above, I've illustrated a proportional sample here since that seems to be what you need.  Cluster sampling would take a little more space to describe.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your fake data so i'll make my own.

i'm assuming you construct your own unique groups.  i've just used the numbers `1:2000` to do it, but you can run this code on any group type..

```
# let's make some fake data with 155k points distributed in 2k groups
x <- 
    data.frame(
        groupname = sample( x = 1:2000 , size = 155000 , replace = TRUE ) ,
        anothercol = 1 ,
        andanothercol = "hi"
    )

# look at your data frame `x`
head( x )
# so long as you've constructed a `groupname` variable in your data, it's easy

# calculate the proportion of each group in the total
groupwise.prob <- table( x$groupname ) / nrow( x )
# store that into a probability vector

# convert this to a data frame
prob.frame <- data.frame( groupwise.prob )

head( prob.frame )

# rename the `Var1` column to match your group name variable on `x`
names( prob.frame )[ 1 ] <- 'groupname'

# rename the `Freq` column to say what it is on `x`
names( prob.frame )[ 2 ] <- 'prob'

# merge these individual probabilities back onto your data frame
x <- merge( x , prob.frame , all.x = TRUE )

# now just use the sample function's prob= parameter off of that
# and scale down the size to what you want
recs.to.samp <-
    sample( 
        1:nrow( x ) , 
        size = 6000 , 
        replace = FALSE , 
        prob = x$prob 
    )

# and now here's your new sample, with proportions in tact
y <- x[ recs.to.samp , ]

head( y )
```

Comment: Sorry for take so much time to answer. As a fake data, this could be enough:
# in R:
gr <- 1:2000
a <- floor(runif(2000, min=0, max=500)-20); a[a<0]<-0
b <- floor(runif(2000, min=0, max=250)-20); b[b<0]<-0
c <- floor(runif(2000, min=0, max=50)-20); c[c<0]<-0
a[a==0 & b==0 & c==0] <- 1
total <- a + b + c
datum <- data.frame(gr,a,b,c,total)
rm(gr,a,b,c,total)

/* In SAS */
data datum;
 do group=1 to 2000;
  a=max(0,floor(ranuni(0)*500-20));
  b=max(0,floor(ranuni(0)*250-20));
  c=max(0,floor(ranuni(0)*50 -20));
  if a=0 and b=0 and c=0 then a=1;
  total=a+b+c;
  output;
 end;
run;

Comment: @jmPicaza that sample data does not have 155,000 records..  but who cares if this solution works?  :)

Comment: I know, Anthony. what is important for me is to get a sample of goups such as points more or less 6000 and weighs of the sample similar to proportions <- c(sum(datum$a)/sum(datum$total),sum(datum$b)/sum(datum$total),sum(datum$c)/sum(datum$total))

Comment: @jmPicaza that is the result of my answer

Comment: You probably don't want to use sample here to sample without replacement and unequal probabilities. See, https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-February/153613.html

Comment: I am building a set of functions to build it. It is done for my actual test, but I want to make it a bit more generic to use it in more cases. It can be used to get sub-populations with proportions similar to the population in certain characteristics as debt, exposition, gender, etc.